# Making money with narrating audiobooks from Germany

Tags: publishing, career, audiobook

I would like to try my hand at narrating audiobooks. I have some experience doing so at librivox.org so I thought I'd give ACX (that's a platform where writers can find narrators for their audiobooks, provided by Amazon) a go, only to find that it is not available to me because I don't live in the US, Canada, the UK or the Republic of Ireland (I would need a taxpayers ID in one of those countries). So I wonder if there is an alternative which would allow me to make some money narrating audiobooks from where I live (Germany).

Does anybody have suggestions for a suitable platform?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about writing or the craft of writing.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE, merendo07! Please take a look at our [tour] page, it should give you a better idea regarding what questions we can or cannot answer.

Comment: The question is fine but I'm not sure if it's on topic for Writing.SE or not.  I think probably not but it is a [tag:career] related to writing.  Is it that far off from editing?  I mean we do have an [tag:audiobook] tag for a reason.

Comment: @Cyn While questions about *writing* audiobooks, or even about something you've written being *published* as an audiobook, would be on-topic, I think asking about how to get a job in the audiobook publishing industry is probably on the wrong side of the topicality dividing line.

Comment: @Chappo it's definitely borderline.  I keep going back and forth about which side of the line I'm on.  But I did vote to keep open.

Comment: @Cyn I voted to close but I keep thinking about retracting my vote! I'm wondering, is it the sort of question we could entertain on Meta rather than simply closing completely?

Comment: @Chappo It would be off topic to ask the question above on Meta.  But it would be perfectly fine if you wanted to talk about this question on Meta, if it was off topic, etc, and include a link to here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article here, it discusses options for German audio.

http://indiesgogerman.com/audiobook-market-germany/

The Tolino is big in Germany, and they sell audio but how they source I don't know.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had a look at that and it seems to be what I am looking for, except that it seems to look for German narrators only. I'd like to narrate English books. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @merendo07 are you American/English living in Germany? Or are you German? The reason I ask is that the vast majority of English audiobooks on ACX have American/English protagonists and the writer is unlikely to choose a narrator with a German accent unless they have written a German character. If you have an American/English accent, you will have far more opportunities.

Comment: Have you tried contacting ACX and asking if there is a way around it? You could also get onto the SPF Community Facebook group and ask the question in there. It's a worldwide community and many many writers have done audio through ACX in that group. Someone may be able to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am German, so I am not a native English speaker, although I have worked hard on my English. I have lived in the UK for almost a year and I'd like to think I have a clean pronunciation. I don't think I could fake a German accent so I'd be useless as a voice actor in that regard. I haven't contacted ACX. They seemed pretty unambiguous about not being able to accept voice actors from Germany at this time, so I didn't think it was worth trying. But I'll have a look at the SPF community, thanks for the suggestion.